# Zip all files with similar names together in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I am trying to zip all files starting with 'scan' into a scan.zip. 
Similarly files starting with 'mpg' into mpfg.zip. I have 5-6 other extensions like .txt .jpg to be zipped in tzt.zip, jpg.zip, etc.

For now, I have a `for` loop to do this job but I was wondering if there is a smarter 1-2 liner command in python 2.7 to achieve this.

```
scan_files = [f for f in os.listdir(tmp_folder) if f.startswith('scan')]
scanlogzip = zipfile.ZipFile('scanlog.zip', 'w')
for j in range(1, len(scan_files)+1):
    scanlogzip.write('scan_%s' % j, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: You don't seem to actually be using the filenames you collected into `scan_files`. Instead, you assume that the files are named "scan_1", "scan_2", .... Is that what you really wanted to do?

Comment: It also seems that these "scan_1", "scan_2" files need to be in the current working directory so that they are found by `scanlogzip.write`. This makes the use of `tmp_folder` confusing. If you can run this script on your side and confirm it works as intended that would be helpful.